# Instructing the Program Counter (PC) to increment

Tags: microcontroller, transistors, digital-logic, integrated-circuit, cpu

I am building an 8bit computer from TTL, in regards to the Program Counter, sometimes I may not want it to increment on each clock pulse, with that in mind, how would I instruct it to increment?

The program counter will receive a clock pulse from a 555 timer every x seconds. The circuit/computer will consist of

- Program Counter
- Register A
- Register B
- ALU
- Instruction Register
- Output Register

It will perform a simple addition.

Would it be possible to increment the PC manually via a switch?

Comment: It is not clear what the question is. Are you asking about logical aspects, or circuitry implementation? What are you trying to accomplish here? What do you mean by "increment the PC manually via a switch"?

Comment: Circuitry Implementation. What do I NEED to tell the PC to increment when an operation has finished? IE: When values have been fully loaded into Register A

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand, but I see that you've already got your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to stop the counter incrementing on every clock pulse you need to gate the clock.

[image]

If the enable signal is LOW then on the next rising edge of the clock the Q output goes LOW and blocks any clock pulses through the AND gate (NAND followed by NOT).

The two inverter gates (made from 2 input NAND) add a small delay to the clock pulse ensuring the Q output (LOW) arrives at the input to the AND gate **before** the rising edge of the clock signal.

When the enable signal goes HIGH the Q output cannot change until the next rising edge of the clock (red line). This ensures the enable signal is synchronized to the clock and the PC gets a full clock pulse.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by designing an 8-bit Program Counter (a series of jk flip flops), then attaching a switch to the **clk** (clock) input. All J and K inputs have to be set high, this allows the flipflop to toggle when a pulse is applied. This is why JK flip flop is commonly used for this kind of task

[image]

For more look at [How to build an 8-bit Computer](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Build-an-8-Bit-Computer/) or at [openbookproject](http://openbookproject.net/electricCircuits/Digital/DIGI_11.html)

Comment: Hi yes, I have seen this instructable. So basically I should connect the clock to my 555 timer pulse, which is split with a switch, which when enabled will allow the PC to increment values?

Comment: Yes but the 555 timer can be the clock (or astable multivibrator). You can look up app-notes or its data sheet. [555 as a clock](http://faculty.tcc.edu/PGordy/Orcad/Clock555.pdf)

Comment: Yes, the clock which is only allowed to increment when I want to grab the next value. Is there a better way to increment the PC however without manual intervention?

Comment: By transfering the clock output of the 555 to the input of the binary counter, you should **read up** on the links i attached. It also really depends on your approach, how much are you reinventing the wheel. You're pretty much recreating an 8051. Alot of the hardware inside can be retrieved as an IC, like the Program counters (or binary counter)

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty much going back to basics, however I'm struggling to understand how you'd stop the PC incrementing on every clock pulse, as some instructions MAY take longer to complete than a single clock cycle?

Comment: You may want to consider a computer architecture class, it's one of the things they talk about, relevant performance measurements like [Cycles-per-Instructions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycles_per_instruction) for example. They offer online on [coursera](https://www.coursera.org/course/comparch), mit opencourseware and many other websites.